# Prove that if $C=A+iB$ is invertible, then so is $A+\lambda B$ for some $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a homework question that I've honestly no idea how to tackle. It goes as:

Let $A$, $B$ be real $n × n$ matrices such that the complex matrix $C = A + iB$ is
invertible. By considering $\det(A+\lambda B)$ as a function of $\lambda$, show that the matrix $A+\lambda B$
is invertible for some real number $\lambda$.

How do I consider $\det(A+\lambda B)$ as a function of $\lambda$?

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $\det(A+\lambda B)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to rule out that $\det(A + \lambda B)$ is not the zero polynomial as a function of $\lambda$. But this is clear because the determinant is non-zero for $\lambda = i$. Thus the determinant is a polynomial which is not the zero polynomial, so how many distinct roots (either real or complex) can it have?

Comment: So the polynomial in λ is non-zero except for n values of λ. So in general the polynomial is non-zero, hence invertible...?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Well, for one thing, $\det (A+\lambda B)$ is indeed a function of $\lambda$, a polynomial in $\lambda$ in fact. Because it is a polynomial, you can tell a lot about the roots of the function (if a polynomial satisfies $p(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, what can you say about $p$?)